# In how many ways can you tile a 3xn rectangle with 2x1 dominoes?

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming

Everyday I struggle with algorithm questions and try to ask here which I can't answer. Excuse me, if I cause any headache. Anyway,

Here is the [problem](http://plg1.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~acm00/050924/D.html) from the University of Waterloo ACM Programming Contest.

> In how many ways can you tile a 3xn rectangle with 2x1 dominoes?

Nirvana : smells like *recursion* spirit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this by using dynamic programming. Check [this](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/UVa_10918) for a possible solution.

Comment: @hitesh_noty the link got dead. I wrote this answer a long time ago when I didn't understand this problem with link only answer. I have found another explanation here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42170/why-do-these-recurrences-determine-the-number-of-ways-of-tiling-a-3xn-rectangle but honestly, I need to edit this answer to add the explanation here so that it doesn't depend on another link.

Answer (score 11):

Just an explicit solution to the equations given implicitly in taskinoor's answer:

[image]

Or

```
f[n]=((1 + (-1)^n)*((2 - Sqrt[3])^(n/2)*(-1 + Sqrt[3]) + 
     (1 + Sqrt[3])* (2 + Sqrt[3])^(n/2)))/(4*Sqrt[3])
```

if anyone cares.

Let's show 10 values (for odd n there are no solutions) {n,f[n]}:

```
{6, 41.},   
{12, 2131.},   
{18, 110771.},   
{24, 5.75796*10^6},   
{30, 2.99303*10^8},   
{36, 1.5558*10^10}, 
{42, 8.08717*10^11},  
{48, 4.20377*10^13}, 
{54, 2.18515*10^15}, 
{60, 1.13586*10^17}
```

Comment: +1. really confused accepting correct answer :). thanks both of you

Comment: @taskinoor It has a curious resemblance of Fibonacci explicit form http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/a/f/9/af9b6b5e3dea6654db4794bd066dd433.png

Comment: @hilal The answer was provided by taskinoor. I just elaborated on that.

Comment: Note that $(2+\sqrt3)^{1/2}=(1+\sqrt3)/\sqrt2$, so this can be simplified

Comment: In fact, for even $n$, it's the integer closest to $$\dfrac{(1+\sqrt3)^{n+1}}{2^{n/2+1}\cdot\sqrt3}$$

Answer (score 3):

Just a note on how to get the explicit solution formula, the trick is to write it down recurrence as matrix multiplication, and then use the eigenvalue formula for `n`th power of a matrix. For the recursion above, the equation is

(not available)

You can see the four eigenvalues show up in the belisarius' explicit formula

Comment: +1: And if you are just looking for an algorithm, just compute the powers of the matrix in O(logn) time, which has the advantage of using only integer arithemetic.

Comment: the image is missing.