# Given 3 x N rectangle, determine how many ways can we tile the rectangle using 1x3 and 3x1 tiles

Tags: algorithm

[image]

How might I approach this problem? I am thinking I try to put tiles, then if I cant put any more, I need to backtrack ... but how do I know how much to backtrack? Also after putting a tile, how might I (the code) decide which next tile to fill and with which type of tile?

Comment: Semi-duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803805/in-how-many-ways-can-you-tile-a-3xn-rectangle-with-2x1-dominoes

Comment: @xanatos: Yes, but this problem is an order of magnitude easier because of the 3-by-1 dominoes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use this recurrence : `F(N) = F(N - 1) + F(N - 3)`
with base case : `F(0) = F(1) = F(2) = 1`

Here, F(N) represents no of ways of tiling a 3XN grid with 3X1 or 1X3 tiles.

- if you place a 3X1 tile, then you just need to solve for `F(N - 1)`.
- if you place a 1x3 tile, then you cant place a 3x1 tile under
  it. Basically, you will have to place a set of three 1x3 tiles
  together, hence you solve for `F(N - 3)`.

Take the sum, and you get the recurrence i mentioned above. 
 
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do in a computer science problem is to understand and reduce it. In this case, try to understand how the height of the rectangle relates to the problem. When placing a tile sideways, is there any option but placing two tiles horizontally under it? So, what tile options do you effectively have? Is it a 2D or a 1D problem?

You should then be able to solve the problem via combinatorics.

Comment: @jiewmeng: You can compute the number of distinct orderings of the elements in a set via the factorial function (x!).

Answer (score 1):

Consider building the 3 by N block from left to right. At any stage, there are essentially two cases to consider: you can place a vertical tile or you can place three horizontal tiles. You can capture these in a recursive function that tries both alternatives and calls itself to build the rest of the block. That is, the number of ways to build a 3 by N block is the number of ways to build a 3 by (N-1) block plus the number of ways to build a 3 by (N-3) block.

As it's homework, I'll leave implementation to you. I'd expect that it could be solved exactly by hand, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think this could be solved purely using integer division and modulus, and a bit of multiplication. no loops needed.

Answer (score 0):

c++ implementation using [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming):

```
int getCount(int n)
{
    vector<int> f(n + 1);
    f[0] = 1;
    f[1] = 1;
    f[2] = 1;
    for(int i = 3; i <= n; i++)
    {
        f[i] = f[i-1] + f[i-3];
    }
    return f[n];
}
```

f(n) - solution for length n. f(n-1) - when you put vertical. f(n-3) - when you put 3 horizontal blocks

Answer (score 0):

Think about how the tiling must look - there are either vertical tiles or else 3x3 blocks of horizontal tiles.  Imagine that these 3x3 blocks are glued together - no loss in doing this.If there are  k  3x3 blocks then there are n - 3k vertical blocks for k =  0, 1, . . .|*n/3*|   where |*j*| is the greatest integer less than or equal to j. There are C(n-2k, k) arrangements possible  where C(x,y) is "n choose y" i.e.  (x!)/((y!)((x-y)!)). So the answer is C(n,0) + C(n-2,1) + C(n-4,2) + . . .C(n - 2, |*n/3*|).  The same method works for the number of tilings of an nxk box with nx1 tiles. In fact, using a small provocative number like 3 could be considered a distraction for the problem. To solve this for boxes with a width bigger than n would require another recursion.
.

Comment: This question is half a year old and has been answered and accepted long time ago. Also, this is an algorithm question, and your answer won't lead to any useful code.